# Как собрать переданный через Socket класс

Tags: java, сокет

на клиентской стороне есть класс Message, в котром есть id юзера и само сообщение. я на стороне клиента преобразую класс в `byte[]` и отправляю через Socket, и собираю в `ByteArrayInputStream`. а как собрать то в Message(на сервере он продублирован),чтобы из него уже брать содеримое?

Comment: Может, вы не класс, а объект преобразуете в byte[] и отправляете по сети? Зависит от способа преобразования. Каждый способ упаковки сопровождается способом распаковки. Если вы упаковывали через ObjectOutputStream, распаковывать надо через ObjectInputStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java - Serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)